# How to position an <ul> (containing animating text) so that it appears in the flow with the rest of the content, rather than hovering over it?

Tags: css, css-position, fixed, absolute

**[JSFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/wxuotshh/1/)**

**PROBLEM:**

*The animating text appears to be stacked on top of the `div` which was coded right after it in the markup, and that `div` appears to be stacked on the top of the background slideshow.*

**So how can I make the animating text in the flow with the `div` with the white background, so that it normally before the `div`, rather than hovering over it.**

**BACKGROUND:**

I have two animations on a single page. One is of full screen image slideshow in the background in an `ul` which is positioned `fixed` *(so when the rest of the content of the page is scrolled, it hovers on top of that page, just like the white background div scrolling here, hovering on the top of a full screen background image).*

So apart from the CSS for animation, following is the HTML and CSS for this part of the page:

```
<ul class="image-slideshow">
            <li>
                <span>Image 01</span>
            </li>
            ....<!-- five more <li> elements -->
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.image-slideshow { 
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: -1; 
}

.image-slideshow li span {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    color: transparent;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: none;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

It's fine so far. What I want next is that there should be a `div` for the rest of the content of the page, and it should contain

1. A text animation, so that apparently the animating text appears to be the titles for the images animating in the background, But the reason I am not adding the text to that very animation is that I want the text to be in the flow with the content other than background slideshow, i.e. the text should scroll with that content, hovering on the top of the background image.
2. Below the `ul` doing the animation of the text, there should be a full width `div` with text and other stuff. So when the page is scrolled, the animating text, and the `div` after it should appear to be stacked on top of the background slideshow.

`<div id="content-other-than-slider">`

```
        <ul class="title-slideshow">
            <li>
                <div><h3>re·lax·a·tion</h3></div>
            </li>
            ...<!-- 6 more <li> elements -->
        </ul> 

    <div><p>...</p></div>
```

`</div>`

***CSS***

```
#content-other-than-slider {
    position:static;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    padding:20px;
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px black;
}

.title-slideshow { 
    position: static;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 0; 
}

.title-slideshow li div { 
    z-index: 1000;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0;
    color: red;
}

.title-slideshow li div h3 { 
    font-family: 'BebasNeueRegular', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 40px;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 200px; 
}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want the red text to stay below the white box? As opposed to what it currently does which is go onto of the box at certain screen dimensions.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ebc4x0oe/ I'm assuming by 'flow' you meant scroll. Originally you have everything `position: fixed;` or `position:static;` so it couldn't scroll. A few tweaks and now the red text scrolls with the rest of the page.

Comment: @AlexeiDarmin Oh no no no. You can see [here](http://blueprintlsat.com/) - there is an images slideshow in the background. then in the foreground there is headings (the uppercase text above the 'Learn More' button.) text (which is animating, i.e. text changing right?) and then below it is the `div` which reads "UPCOMING LAST COURSES" and then below it is rest of the content.

Comment: @AlexeiDarmin Apart from the background image slideshow, all the rest of the content is scrolling up and down as a single unit. All the divs (except the background image slideshow) are aligned one after the other, just as they are coded in the HTML code. But in my example, the heading text is hovering over the rest of the content, which is hovering over the background slideshow.

Comment: @AlexeiDarmin Let me know I still did not make it clear, I can explain it on chat. I'll greatly appreciate any help, as I am completely lost in this.

Comment: I see, the issue is the same as before however. You have assigned `position:absolute` and `position:static;` to the content. This removes it from being synchronized with the rest of the content and you get the issue of content appearing ontop of other content. The only object that should have a non-`position:relative;` assignment for this is the background slideshow. Which is correctly `position:fixed;`